# Table with an angle | rotate the co-ordintae

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, rotation, table

I have the following,

```
Flatten[MapAt[Reverse, 2]@
Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10, 10}, {j, 0, 90, 90}], 1]
```

that gives,

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 90}, {10, 90}, {10, 0}}
```

which are basically a rectangle coordinates, and shape will be

[image]

**is there anyway I can rotate the coordinates by 45 degree**, so the shape will look like the following,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a rotation by using "GeometricTransformation" together with "RotationTransfrom". For your example we draw a line with the given coordinates:

```
dat = Flatten[
   MapAt[Reverse, 2]@Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10, 10}, {j, 0, 90, 90}], 1];
dat = Append[dat, dat[[1]]];
Graphics[{Line[dat]}]
```

[image]

Now we rotate the shape:

```
rot = RotationTransform[-Pi/4];
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Line[dat], rot]]
```

[image]

To get the rotated coordinates, write:

```
rot[dat]

{{0, 0}, {45 Sqrt[2], 45 Sqrt[2]}, {50 Sqrt[2], 
  40 Sqrt[2]}, {5 Sqrt[2], -5 Sqrt[2]}, {0, 0}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to rotate the co-ordinates rather than the shape (GeometricTransformation).

Comment: I added this part.